# Python Version help on Mac

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

I currently have Python3.9 installed on my mac but when I used python3 --version it says that I am still using python3.7. I am currently trying to switch the version but I do not want to effect the python version that is being used on Mac's software system. Also I am also trying to use Pexpect on the program I am writing, it says that it is successfully installed but under the bin of python3.9 and not 3.7. So when I run my program it says ModuleNotFound.

I am currently using this link to help me with switching the version that I am running my python programs: [link](https://dev.to/malwarebo/how-to-set-python3-as-a-default-python-version-on-mac-4jjf#:%7E:text=Open%20the%20terminal%20(bash%20or,https%3A%2F%2Fbrew.sh).&text=Look%20where%20it%20is%20installed.&text=Change%20the%20default%20python%20symlink,want%20to%20use%20from%20above.) .

Does anyone have any tips or recommendations on this issue

Comment: If you don't want t mess up with the current python version, one solution would be to use a conda virtual environment. If you have conda installed, just run `conda create -n "myenv" python=3.9`.

Comment: Run `type python3` to see full path to the Python that will be used when you use `python3 -V` or `python3 someScript.py`. Set your `PATH` to some other place if you want to run some other Python. Read the output from `brew info python3` if you installed using **homebrew**.